# C# Do While looping problems

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I'm really stuck on this C# do while loop business. After a long time of messing with it I finally got it to loop a statement, but now it just repeats whatever statement was made first. For example, if it generates the number 6 and you guess 7 it'll say "too high..." but then when you guess again whether you're too low or equal to 6, it will still say "too high..."

Thanks

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        int intRandomNum;

        // ask the random num gen for num between 1 and 12
        intRandomNum = r.Next(10) + 1;

        //ask user for their first guess
        Console.WriteLine("I'm going to generate a random number, can you guess what it is? " + intRandomNum);

        int intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        do
        {

            if (intUserNum == intRandomNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You got it! Great job!");
            }

            if (intUserNum < intRandomNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too low! Try Again.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            if (intUserNum > intRandomNum)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too high! Try again.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        } while (intUserNum != intRandomNum);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

**Thanks everyone for the help! I got it! Finally!**

Comment: Reed has the right answer, but as a side note, you should probably either move the "You got it right!" out of the loop (as it will break when it is correct and hit that link). That stops you from doing the same check twice.  just basic optimization

Answer (score 5):

You need to put your parse inside of your loop, so that you re-compute `intUserNum`.

```
    int intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    do
    {

        if (intUserNum == intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You got it! Great job!");
        }

        if (intUserNum < intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too low! Try Again.");
            intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        if (intUserNum > intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too high! Try again.");
            intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    } while (intUserNum != intRandomNum);
```

Your code, as written, reads a new line from the user, but it never turns it into a number, so your variable never changes.  This causes your first incorrect guess to be used forever.

Note that it might also be a good idea to look at using [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of `int.Parse`.  This allows you to handle if the user types something that isn't an integer...

Answer (score 1):

Move the input reading inside the loop:

```
int intUserNum;

    do
    {
        intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (intUserNum == intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You got it! Great job!");
        }

        if (intUserNum < intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too low! Try Again.");
        }
        if (intUserNum > intRandomNum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too high! Try again.");
        }

    } while (intUserNum != intRandomNum);
```

Comment: Need to remove the call to `Console.ReadLine();` inside the `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the code that actually fetches a number from the user into `intUserNum`, namely

```
int intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

is *outside* the loop, so it will only get executed once. Every time the loop repeats, it checks the same old number.

Coding tip: Remember that the computer has no idea of what you *intend* to do. Your intention was probably the correct one, namely that `intUserNum` should always contain the next number the user guesses. However, the computer only does what you told it to, and you told it that the user should only enter a number once - inside the loop, you never say that `intUserNum` should take on a new value, and so it will retain its old value forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
int intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Should be at the top of the loop.

Don't know C# but that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch and parse the input *inside* your loop. Otherwise the value stays the same all the time:

```
// ...

do
{
    int intUserNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (intUserNum == intRandomNum)
        Console.WriteLine("You got it! Great job!");

    if (intUserNum < intRandomNum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Too low! Try Again.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    if (intUserNum > intRandomNum)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Too high! Try again.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

} while (intUserNum != intRandomNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rnd = new Random();
    var n = rnd.Next(13);

    while (!Guess(n)) ;

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static bool Guess(int n)
{
    int input;

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input))
        return false;

    var msg = input == n ? "Win" : input < n ? "Low" : "High";
    Console.WriteLine(msg);

    return input == n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my own and was struggling for almost two whole class sessions until I found your answer while (ironically) in the process of typing my own question.

```
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string aKnight = "Romulus";
            string bKnight = "Remus";
            string Weapon;


            Console.WriteLine($"{aKnight} implies {bKnight} is unorthodox.");
            /*Console.ReadLine();*/

            Console.WriteLine($"{bKnight} deicdes to hit {aKnight}. What should he use? Club, Bow, or Tactical Nuke?");
            /*Console.ReadLine();*/


            do
            {
                Weapon = Console.ReadLine();
                switch (Weapon)
                {

                    case "Club":
                        Console.WriteLine("Works for me.");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{bKnight} knocks {aKnight} out with the club.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "Bow":
                        Console.WriteLine("Eh, creative yet acceptable.");
                        Console.WriteLine($"{bKnight} hits {aKnight} over the head with the bow. It just hurt a little.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    case "Tactical Nuke":
                        Console.WriteLine("Are.. Are you serious? For the love of... JUST WHY?!");
                        Console.WriteLine("TACTICAL NUKE INBOUND!!!... It lagged...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Please make a choice.");
                        //Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                }
            } while (Weapon != default && Weapon != "Club" && Weapon != "Bow" && Weapon != "Tactical Nuke");

                Console.WriteLine("What will happen next ?");
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

All I needed to do was move Weapon = Console.ReadLine() into the do/while brackets and add (&& Weapon != "Club" && Weapon != "Bow" && Weapon != "Tactical Nuke") into the parenthesis. Thanks a lot! :D